# How to transform X and Y from LV95 to Lat Long with pyproj

Tags: pyproj, switzerland

I am trying to convert data from

LV95 (Berne = 2600 / 1200 km)
to
WGS84 (~ETRS89)

Is this possible with pyproj.

I'm trying like this

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
inProj = Proj(init='CH:1903_LV03')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

lat_long = transform(inProj,outProj,"2680689.73","1245165.39")
print(lat_long)
```

but how to define init= isn't clear to me. I was testing some things I found here https://gist.github.com/procrastinatio/d9dc3431a2cc9dd92b96 but never found how to deal with LV95.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google search returned the [EPSG code of 2056](https://epsg.io/2056) so:

```
from pyproj import Transformer

transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:2056", "epsg:4326")
print(transformer.transform(2680689.73,1245165.39))
```

This returns:
(47.352401265646414, 8.506591321239927)

Comment: transform is deprecated. Mind updating your example to use the Transformer instead? See: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#upgrading-to-pyproj-2-from-pyproj-1

Comment: @snowman2 Thanks, code updated.

Comment: Thanks for updating 